# localhost opens in opera instead of chrome. how do I change it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, browser, visual-studio-code

When I run my dev environment it immediately opens up localhost:3000 or any other of my choosing in Opera instead of chrome. 
How do I change it so that Opera will not be used at all?

Comment: How do you 'run' your dev environment exactly? EDIT: I guess Visual Studio opens it for you. Then, it must be a preference inside Visual Studio.

Comment: what's your pc's default browser?

Comment: Change your default browser to be chrome, should be in the chrome settings.

Comment: yep, changed my default browser and that was it. Thanks